# How to briefly use last ignored (not saved in history file) command in bash?

Tags: bash, bash-history

In my bash config file .bashrc,I have set it up in a way that commands preceded by a space are not saved in history. What I am asking is, how to achieve similar function as this answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/352858) which was used for zsh. I want to be able to access last command even though it is not stored in history.

Comment: The answer you refer to is about *enabling* ignoring a command. It is not about accessing an ignored command. I do not think what you ask is possible: the command that was not stored in history = gone

Comment: Maybe I need to redact my question. The thing is I want to access only the last command no matter if it has preceding spaces or not, just for the session. And if the command is preceded by space, next session it will not be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Bash stores a command in history so you can retrieve it later. A command that is not stored in history, for example, because you preceded it with a space, or you deleted it later from the history with the `history -d` command, is gone from the history and cannot, by definition, be recalled. Not in bash, and not in zsh.

Of course, in terminal emulators, or if you use `screen` or `tmux`, you always can copy paste the command if it is still visible earlier in the buffer.